# Custom row/checkbox template for Kendo UI grid

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a custom row template for a Kendo UI grid that includes the checkbox functionality. I have the grid created like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Users)
              .Name("usersGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Select().Width(50);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.UserName);
              })
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .ServerOperation(false))
              .ClientRowTemplate(UsersClientTemplate))
```

With a function to generate the row template like this:

```
Func<Grid<User>, string> UsersClientTemplate = (grid) =>
{
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    return @"<tr data-uid='#:uid#' role='row'>" +
           "<td role='gridcell'>" +
           $"<input class='k-checkbox' data-role='checkbox' type='checkbox' id={id}>" +
           $"<label class='k-checkbox-label k-no-text' for={id}>​</label>" +
           "</td>" +
           "<td role='gridcell'>" +
           "<a href='/users/details/#:data.Id#'>#:data.UserName#</a>" +
           "</td>" +
           "</tr>";
};
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to generate the unique ids for each row's template. If I don't include the `id` attribute on the checkbox `input` element and the `for` attribute on the checkbox `label` element, the checkbox/row selection doesn't work. But with the function I have above, the same id is generated for every row template and then the checkbox/row selection only works for the first row, obviously.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are generated when the grid is built so as you have seen the id is always the same. What you want is to databind so kendo replaces the id with each record. I use my entity key with a prefix like "cb_" for checkbox:

```
       $"<input class='k-checkbox' data-role='checkbox' type='checkbox' id='cb_#:uid#'>" +
       $"<label class='k-checkbox-label k-no-text' for='cb_#:uid#'>​</label>" +
```

Comment: I had the same solution already (using the `uid`) but it felt a bit hacky - I was hoping there was a way to grab the index somehow and append that to a guid or something. But I wasn't using a prefix (like `cb_`) - that's not a bad idea and makes it seem a little less hacky. If there aren't any better answers by tomorrow or next day I'll mark this as solution. Thank you!!

Comment: Another option would be to create the Ids in your server side calls and include a new property in the model to bind to.